# python help separating lists in a text file

Tags: python, list

I have a text file with hundreds of lists stored in a text file. How could i separate the lists and then store them as lists and search for the smallest second value between the lists. I am open to any new ways of tackling this problem. Here is the first few 'lists' and my attempt to separate them

```
var line1=[["Apr 02 2014 01: +0",0.6,"295"],["Apr 03 2014 01: +0",0.641,"245"],["Apr 04 2014 01: +0",0.625,"246"],["Apr 05 2014 01: +0",0.665,"267"],["Apr 06 2014 01: +0",0.632,"226"],["Apr 07 2014 01: +0",0.672,"170"],["Apr 08 2014 01: +0",0.655,"147"],["Apr 09 2014 01: +0",0.654,"121"],["Apr 10 2014 01: +0",0.62,"136"],["Apr 11 2014 01: +0",0.629,"176"],["Apr 12 2014 01: +0",0.68,"190"],["Apr 13 2014 01: +0",0.677,"176"],["Apr 14 2014 01: +0",0.73,"153"],["Apr 15 2014 01: +0",0.587,"148"],["Apr 16 2014 01: +0",0.591,"134"],["Apr 17 2014 01: +0",0.612,"148"],["Apr 18 2014 01: +0",0.593,"142"],["Apr 19 2014 01: +0",0.612,"153"],["Apr 20 2014 01: +0",0.654,"203"],["Apr 21 2014 01: +0",0.713,"156"],["Apr 22 2014 01: +0",0.711,"153"],["Apr 23 2014 01: +0",0.625,"128"],["Apr 24 2014 01: +0",0.629,"122"],["Apr 25 2014 01: +0",0.603,"139"],["Apr 26 2014 01: +0",0.6,"169"],["Apr 27 2014 01: +0",0.589,"177"],["Apr 28 2014 01: +0",0.585,"132"],["Apr 29 2014 01: +0",0.612,"120"],["Apr 30 2014 01: +0",0.626,"116"],["May 01 2014 01: +0",0.57,"142"]
```

and my attempt to separate them

```
with open('test.txt','r') as csvfile:
  writer=csv.reader(csvfile,delimeter=' , ',quotechar=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in writer:
      print ','.join(row)
```

Comment: Does the input end with another `]`?

Comment: Ok, but my point is that in your example, the first `[` does not have a corresponding `]`.

Comment: yes sorry it does end with a ]

Comment: What you mean by *hundreds of lists* exactly? do you mean hundreds of lists like `line 1` and does all of them stored with a preceding `var`?

Comment: no there is only one var line1 and they all are in the same format of ["Apr 02 2014 01: +0",0.6,"295"] each separated with a , and the entire text document starts with var line1=[ (lists in here) then ends with ];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, assuming this is representative input as far as format is concerned:

```
var line1=[["Apr 02 2014 01: +0",0.6,"295"],["Apr 03 2014 01: +0",0.641,"245"]];
```

Then you could do the following:

```
import json

with open('test.txt', 'r') as datafile:
    data = datafile.read()

json_str = data.split('=', 1)[1].rstrip(';\n\r ')
my_data = json.loads(json_str)

for row in my_data:
    print row

print "Minimum by second value"
print min(my_data, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Which will print:

```
[u'Apr 02 2014 01: +0', 0.6, u'295']
[u'Apr 03 2014 01: +0', 0.641, u'245']
Minimum by second value
[u'Apr 02 2014 01: +0', 0.6, u'295']
```

Comment: I tried this but came up with an error  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    my_data = json.loads(json_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 38314 - line 1 column 38316 (char 38313 - 38315)

Comment: You're going to have to look around column 38314 to figure out what that's saying. Sounds like the format deviates from what you've shown.

Comment: character 38314 is the comma between the penultimate and the last list here they are and the end of the file ["Jul 05 2015 15: +0",0.211,"15"],["Jul 05 2015 16: +0",0.211,"11"]];

Comment: oh, right, sorry, it's actually going to be between around character 38314 of `json_str`. Try print(json_str[38310:38320])

Comment: Ah, it's possible there's whitespace at the end of the line, try what I just changed (with the space added in the rstrip string). If that fails, try print(repr(json_str[38310:38320])). Hopefully that will be verbose enough to show the problem.

Comment: it hit the same error again but printed this now ']];\r'

Comment: Ah, you're on windows. Try with 'rt' in the open call. That'll open it in text mode which will convert windows style "\r\n"'s into unix style "\n"'s.

Comment: im using linux it doesnt change anything i tried rb and that didnt work either

Comment: Ok, just put \r in the rstrip like I did then. I should rephrase, your file is has DOS/Windows style line endings. Apparently 't' is the default and 'b' can be specified, anyhow, on linux the text mode won't convert the Windows style line endings because you're not on Windows.

Comment: Awesome thank you, how would i now compare those lists for the lowest second value

Comment: By "second value" do you mean the number that comes after the date?

Comment: the number after the first ,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.finditer()` to get your expected lists within a generator.which is an optimized way for saving your memory.

Then you can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert your string to a list object :

```
import ast
import re
with open(filename) as f:
     all_list=re.finditer(r'\[([^[\]]*?)\]',f)
```

Demo:

```
print [ast.literal_eval(i.group()) for i in all_list]

[['Apr 02 2014 01: +0', 0.6, '295'], ['Apr 03 2014 01: +0', 0.641, '245'], ['Apr 04 2014 01: +0', 0.625, '246'], ['Apr 05 2014 01: +0', 0.665, '267'], ['Apr 06 2014 01: +0', 0.632, '226'], ['Apr 07 2014 01: +0', 0.672, '170'], ['Apr 08 2014 01: +0', 0.655, '147'], ['Apr 09 2014 01: +0', 0.654, '121'], ['Apr 10 2014 01: +0', 0.62, '136'], ['Apr 11 2014 01: +0', 0.629, '176'], ['Apr 12 2014 01: +0', 0.68, '190'], ['Apr 13 2014 01: +0', 0.677, '176'], ['Apr 14 2014 01: +0', 0.73, '153'], ['Apr 15 2014 01: +0', 0.587, '148'], ['Apr 16 2014 01: +0', 0.591, '134'], ['Apr 17 2014 01: +0', 0.612, '148'], ['Apr 18 2014 01: +0', 0.593, '142'], ['Apr 19 2014 01: +0', 0.612, '153'], ['Apr 20 2014 01: +0', 0.654, '203'], ['Apr 21 2014 01: +0', 0.713, '156'], ['Apr 22 2014 01: +0', 0.711, '153'], ['Apr 23 2014 01: +0', 0.625, '128'], ['Apr 24 2014 01: +0', 0.629, '122'], ['Apr 25 2014 01: +0', 0.603, '139'], ['Apr 26 2014 01: +0', 0.6, '169'], ['Apr 27 2014 01: +0', 0.589, '177'], ['Apr 28 2014 01: +0', 0.585, '132'], ['Apr 29 2014 01: +0', 0.612, '120'], ['Apr 30 2014 01: +0', 0.626, '116'], ['May 01 2014 01: +0', 0.57, '142']]
```

Note that you can process every list in each iteration and you are not forced to get all the list at once.

```
for i in all_list:
   # do stuff with ast.literal_eval(i.group())
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work as long as the data isn't too long(so it fits in memory)

```
import json

filename = "D:\\tmp\\test.txt"


final_lists = []

with open(filename, "r") as fl:
    #Read everything
    content = fl.read()

#Now split first line to keep only the lists
valid_part = content.split("=", 1)[1]
#Load valid part into json
cur_lists = json.loads(valid_part)

#Now find min value
_min = min(cur_lists, key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Comment: this hits the same error as the first answer he suggests there may be a white space at the end

Comment: Well we did go for the same method. I think he is correct something at the end of your string is messing up the format, json is quite sensetive.. Try adding replacing his rstrip with .rstrip(';\n\r ')